# Por que razon no me envia a el else en PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

require_once('conexion.php');

   $usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
   $clave = md5($_GET["clave"]);

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '$usuario' and clave = '$clave'" );
   //echo $result;

   if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      if($row["clave"] == $clave)
      {
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
         header("location: ../index.php");
      }
      else
      {
        echo "(Hola)";

      }
   }
else
{
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      header.location("../login.php");
      alert("El nombre de usuario es incorrecto!");
    </script>
  <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Login html php:

```
<html>
    <head>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
              <meta name="author" content="www.intercambiosvirtuales.org" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bootgrid.css"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css">

              <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
              <script src="js/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/login.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" >
    </head>
  <body>
    <BODY BACKGROUND="img/sfondo.jpg">
    <div id="container" style="min-width:800px;">
      <div class="left">
      </div>
       <div class="center">

            <br>
              <h2>LOGIN :v.</h2>
                <div  class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 30px;">
                  <form method="get" action="php/login.php">
                    <br>
                    <label >Usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" maxleght="8" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" required>
                    <p>
                    <label>Contrase&ntilde;a: </label>
                    <input type="password" maxleght="8" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="clave" name="clave" required>
                    <p>
                    <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" id="boton1"class="btn btn-success" name="boton1">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='login.html'">
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="right">
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más especifico? ¿A que Else te refieres?

Comment: si logea pero al momento de la contraseña ser erronea no me envia el echo hola;

Comment: que quiero que me redireccione a el mismo sitio a login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer punto tu consulta **SQL** es susceptible a inyección **SQL** te recomiendo leas la documentación en como crear sentencias preparadas por seguridad [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

En segunda, tu le estas diciendo que si no tiene filas tu consulta se vaya a este **ELSE**

```
else
{
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      header.location("../login.php");
      alert("El nombre de usuario es incorrecto!");
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

Por eso no te muestra el que contiene el `echo "Hola"`
porque no cumple con el primer **IF** ya que tu consulta busca usuario y password al mandarle uno mal no encuentra nada.

Comment: si ya logre solucionar eso y es una practica escolar la seguridad no importa mucho

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la logica de tu script:
`$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '$usuario' and clave = '$clave'" );`
Esta variable ($result) solo será diferente de nulo cuando los 2 campos sean iguales y en caso de que la contraseña sea errónea llegará al primer IF y no entrará en este y nunca comparaá la clave.

Como dato adicional, a la próxima estructura y plantea mejor tu pregunta.